# Create an environment/counter named with a given macro

Tags: macros, environments

I'm trying to create an environment with a given macro as name:

```
\newcommand{\newproblemset}[1]{\newenvironment{#1}{}}
\newproblemset{problem}
```

However, the compiler gives the following error, though I don't define `\problem` directly:

```
LaTeX Error: Command \problem already defined.
```

The purpose is that I want to create a command, that supports creating an environment with a user-specified environment name.

Another issue arises when I want to define a counter with user-specified name. Although I managed to create the counter successfully, I don't how to refer to that counter, since the counter name should be in the form of `\the` followed by the counter name.

It seems the issue lies in the way how LaTeX does macro expansion. In fact, what I want to do is exactly what `\newtheorm` does, which creates an environment with user-given names.

Update: a full example

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\newproblemset}[1]{\newenvironment{#1}{c1}{c2}}
\newproblemset{aa}

\begin{document}

    \begin{aa}
        content
    \end{aa}

\end{document}
```

Compiler's error:

```
root.tex
LaTeX Error: Command \aa already defined.
```

For defining a counter:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\newproblemset}[1]{\newcounter{#1}[section]\renewenvironment{#1}{c1 \refstepcounter{#1} \the#1 }{c2}}
\newproblemset{aa}

\begin{document}

    \begin{aa}
        aa
    \end{aa}

\end{document}
```

It gives an error:

```
root.tex (line 8)
You can't use `the letter a' after \the. (  \begin{aa} ...)
```

Comment: I can't replicate the problem with the current code snippet. You must have some other package included that defines a `problem` environment (or command). Also, `\newenvironment` takes 3 arguments, not just 2: One for the environment name, one for the `\begin` part of the environment and a final one for the `\end` part.

Comment: @Werner  Using ``\newcommand{\newproblemset}[1]{\newenvironment{#1}{}{}}
\newproblemset{aa}`` gives the same error `\aa is defined`. I'm using XeLaTeX.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example that replicates the current issue. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and allow us to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're experiencing. It should be *minimal* though, only the necessary packages that replicates the behaviour. Can you do that?

Comment: @Werner updated.

Comment: Well, `\aa` is a command already (see the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](//texdoc.net/pkg/comprehensive)). It would be different for `problem`, which doesn't exist by default. Do you want to define `\newproblemset` to completely ignore whether a command already exists?

Comment: @Werner Thanks! I understand. But how should I refer to the defined counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific example, defining a new environment like `aa` won't work since the environment `aa` is defined by `\aa` and `\endaa`, and [the former (`\aa`) is already defined by default](//texdoc.net/pkg/comprehensive) as Angstrom.

You could create `\newproblemset` to completely ignore whether a command is already defined using the following definition:

```
\newcommand{\newproblemset}[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname #1\endcsname\relax% Remove definition of \<#1>
  \newenvironment{#1}{c1}{c2}}% Define new environment
```

The above definition sets `\<#1>` to `\relax` - one of the conditions used to check whether something already exists or not. Of course, you can go that one step further and issue a warning if the command already exists (but define the environment anyway):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newproblemset}[1]{%
  \ifcsname #1\endcsname
    \@latex@warning{Environment `#1' will overwrite `\expandafter\string\csname #1\endcsname'.}%
    \expandafter\let\csname #1\endcsname\relax % Make sure \<#1> is available for (re)definition
  \fi
  \newenvironment{#1}{c1}{c2}}% Define new environment
\makeatother

\newproblemset{aa}

\begin{document}

\begin{aa}
content
\end{aa}

\end{document}
```

This outputs

> LaTeX Warning: Environment `aa' will overwrite`\aa'. on input line 11.

in the `.log`.

For printing the counter, instead of `\the#1`, you need `\csname the#1\endcsname` to properly constructing something that resembles `\the#1`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newproblemset}[1]{%
  \ifcsname #1\endcsname
    \@latex@warning{Environment `#1' will overwrite `\expandafter\string\csname #1\endcsname'.}%
    \expandafter\let\csname #1\endcsname\relax % Make sure \<#1> is available for (re)definition
  \fi
  \newcounter{#1}[section]% Define a new counter
  \newenvironment{#1}{c1 \refstepcounter{#1}\csname the#1\endcsname}{c2}}
\makeatother

\newproblemset{aa}

\begin{document}

\begin{aa}
aa
\end{aa}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\newcommand{\newproblemset}[1]{\newenvironment{#1}{}}
```

is missing the third argument to `\newenvironment` which isn't necessarily an error if you provide the argument when calling `\newproblemset` (although odd that you just supply the end code not the start code).

This runs without error and produces

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

    \newcommand{\newproblemset}[1]{\newenvironment{#1}{}}

\begin{document}

\newproblemset{zz}{end code}

\begin{zz}
  abc
\end{zz}
\end{document}
```

It also runs without error with your suggested name `problem`

```
\documentclass{article}

    \newcommand{\newproblemset}[1]{\newenvironment{#1}{}}

\begin{document}

\newproblemset{problem}{end code}

\begin{problem}
  abc
\end{problem}
\end{document}
```

If you get the error shown then you have previously already defined a `problem` environment or (equivalently) a `\problem` command, in which case you will need `\renewenvironment` not `\newenvironment`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I've included a full example. Could you please help me check that?